# adding textarea to wordpress options-general.php

Tags: wordpress, textarea, field

I don't know exactly how to define my question, im working on my custom Wordpress theme, and I've added custom input field in General Settings in Wordpress admin, by editing general.php and adding a new array in general list, then i created a new tablerow in options-general.php:

```
<tr valign="top">
<th scope="row"><label for="siteupdates"><?php _e('Site Updates') ?></label></th>
<td><input name="siteupdates" type="text" id="content" 
"value="<?php  form_option('siteupdates'); ?>" class="regular-text" ></>
<span class="description"><?php _e('Site news,updates,etc.') ?></span></td>
</tr>
```

and also added a div in header.php where i wanted it to be shown:

```
<div id="siteInfo">
<?php form_option('siteupdates'); ?>
</div><!--siteInfo end-->
```

then i added new Query in wordpress database in phpmyadmin ('siteupdates') and everything works great,since im very new in php, i have watched lots of tutorials and found that way was the easiest for me.
Now i want to change this input to a textarea field, but when i changed html to:

```
<tr valign="top">
<th scope="row"><label for="siteupdates"><?php _e('Site updates') ?></label></th>
<td><textarea name="siteupdates" type="text" id="content" 
cols="50" rows="6" value="<?php form_option('siteupdates'); ?>" class="regular-text">   
</textarea>
<span class="description"><?php _e('Site news,updates,etc.') ?></span></td>
</tr>
```

Its looks fine, i see textfield instead of input, but i cant store data in it. Where am i wrong?

Comment: It's not ideal to edit files from the `wp-admin` folder as they'll break when/if you upgrade your WP install.

Comment: im aware of that, but i don't know other way to do this, editing functions.php is way to complicated for me, if some of you could explain me how to do it in proper way.

Comment: You should look at [adding your own option pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus)

Answer (score 2):

I just did exactly what you did, i inserted the same code in options-general.php to ad a new field and i created a new record on "options" table.

When i go through General Adjustmenst i see the new field with the value that i early inserted on the new record. But when i try to update it nothing happens.

But i found the options.php if you accces it from browser, you can find all the adjustmets, the interesting point, is if i try to update the value of the new record, it does!!!

This method is really simple, because the right way, create a plugin and so on, its take to much time and more complicated.

If this solution if for myself, ill do it, but if is for someone else, could be rought cause he has to modify the code every new version of wordpress comes out.

Answer (score 1):

A few things :

a) Look into creating your own Administrative menus. [More information here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus)

b) Instead of storing your options with custom db queries, you should use [`add_option`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus)

c) Your textarea has a `type="text"` which isn't needed.

d) If you are going to have content in there, you should look into [`wp_editor`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) It's new in WP 3.3

Answer (score 1):

Change your <textarea> into this one:

```
<textarea name="siteupdates" type="text" id="content" 
cols="50" rows="6" class="regular-text"><?php form_option('siteupdates'); ?></textarea>
```

Bascially get rid of the value attribute and use the content inside the textarea tag.